# Calculating Linear force required to hit a specific vertex on a parabola

Tags: physics, mathematics, lua, corona-sdk

The idea is a user presses somewhere on the screen and the program will fire an object in a parabola shape from a defined start position that has it's vertex where the user touched the screen.

I have managed to use the two points I have to get the quadratic equation in vertex form, and converted it to standard form ok but I don't know how to get the values required for setLinearVelocity vx and vy in corona sdk.

Current code is:

```
-- given vertex and another point find the parabola formula in vertex form
-- y=a(x−h)2+k
local y, a, x, h, k, xh
h = event.x   
k = event.y
x = xStartPos
y = yStartPos

-- solve for a
xh = (x - h) * (x - h)
y = y + (k * -1)
a = y / xh

-- convert to quadratic formula
-- y = ax^2 + bx + c
local b, c
b = -2 * a * h
c = a * (h * h) + k

local vx, vy = -- calculate something here
proj:setLinearVelocity( vx,vy )
```

Comment: Hi, I started writing out an answer but halfway through got a bit confused about your approach. The problem was that if the start and end points are at the same height, i.e. `yStartPos = event.y` then you find `a = 0` which means that you no longer have a parabola. Feel free to correct me. (I will have another crack at an answer tomorrow but also want to check if you are simulating some sort of gravity i.e. firing a cannonball, as I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do).

Comment: Hi George - I do have gravity set to -9.8ms. I've been working in the problem today and maybe I can make it a bit clearer. With standard gravity set in box2d physics engine what linear velocity should I give to an object so that it starts from coords (60,260) and hits the vertex at (280,120)

Comment: if yStartPos = event.y it will need to have a very large vx value, but it would still technically form a parabola ... actually maybe not - this could be a potential bug, I will force the user to select a event.y value above yStartPos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quick note: I don't know lua, however I am fairly good at maths/physics and please bear with me if I cover ideas you are already familiar with.

For any object under the force of gravity the horizontal component of the velocity, `vx`, will remain constant throughout the motion.

[image: Parabolic Motion of a ball source: https://animationphysics.pbworks.com/f/1246396681/TossedBall_ArcTrack.jpg]

In this picture the red dots are made at equal times, so the ball travels equal distances in the `x` direction every tick (so `vx` is constant) whereas it does not in the `y` direction.

**The following does not answer your question directly but is useful so I have left it in**

It is possible to solve the problem, given a starting position `(x0, y0)` and a final position `(xf,yf)` what velocity does the object need initially to reach the final point. This can be solved using [equations of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion), defining `(vx,vy)` as initial velocities, `T` as the time to complete the motion and `g` as the acceleration due to gravity,

```
xf = x0 + vx*T               // This has no acceleration part as it is zero for x
yf = y0 + vy*T - g*T^2/2
```

solving these two equations gives

```
vy = vx * (yf - y0)/(xf - x) + g * (xf - x0)/(2 * vx).
```

Now this is not a complete solution as you know the motion is parabolic but it takes **three points** to define a parabola. So you are going to need to choose either the time it takes for the particle to reach its final spot or the velocity in the x direction.

**Actual answer**

You choose that the final point `(xf,yf)` to be the vertex of the parabola, this does in fact introduce a third constraint, as you mentioned in the comments, this time on the velocity in the `y` direction.

As you found in the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785375/calculate-initial-velocity-to-reach-height-y) the `vy` required is given by,

```
vy = sqrt(2 * g * (yf - y0)).
```

You can then use the equation above for `vy` in terms of `vx` to solve for `vx` which gives,

```
vx = (xf - x0) * sqrt(g / (2 * (yf - y0))).
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The parabola in this case can be defined by two points as one of the points is the vertex. I found a half solution here

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785375/calculate-initial-velocity-to-reach-height-y

However I'm having some trouble translating it to the code...

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood your question, I will edit my answer to reflect this. (For some reason my mind totally ignored the part where the final point is the vertex)

Answer (score 0):

George has answered this correctly - I just wanted to include the working code in case someone needs it in future. I did not need to convert the values to a quadratic equation in the end

The extra sums in the code such as dy * 30 is to convert between pixels and metres and back again, and were a major cause of being unable to convert the maths to code.

```
local dy = (yf - y0) * 30
local dx = (xf - x0) * 30
local t = 1 / display.fps
local a = t * t * -9.8


vy = math.sqrt(2 * a * dy) * display.fps * -1
vx = dx * math.sqrt(a / (2 * dy)) * display.fps


local startingVelocity = { x=vx,  y=vy}
```